# Order of execution PropertyChanges

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, state-machine

Is there any documented order of execution of [`PropertyChanges`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-propertychanges.html) instances?

For example, if there is a [`State`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-state.html) like,

```
State {
    name: "LOADED"
    PropertyChanges { target: elem1; width: 10 }
    PropertyChanges { target: elem2; width: 10 }
}
```

is there any specific order which elements width will be setted first?

Comment: You could try an `onWidthChanged: console.log("e1 changed)` to see what the order is and whether it is consistent, which it should be

Comment: @ddriver yes, I actually asked that question after I saw that there is no any consistent behaviour for this, at least I could not figured it out.

Comment: In that case the order is arbitrary, much like `onCompleted` for nested objects... You could change the properties in code though, they will change in the order you change them.

Comment: @ddriver Yes it seems like arbitrary (maybe depends on the type of the property). I was actually doing with a procedural code before but after watching some Qt videos, I felt like I am doing wrong with procedural code in QML. Because that particular video was highly recommends to use declarative code instead of procedural.

Comment: Pf... like you can't implement states in another way. It happens to me all the time, lots of Qt just doesn't work the way I need it to, so I do it my way. If the order is critical and states do not guarantee it, then do it your way.

Comment: @ddriver Yes that is exactly!! :D you actually articulate my feelings.. So yes it seems like I do need to write procedural. Thank you for helping. Cheers.