# QML: Order of execution of state changes

Tags: qt, qml, state, qtquick2

Is there a defined order of execution of changes when an `Item` changes `state`?

For clarity, my question is **not** about the [order of execution of changes within a single state as asked elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643036/order-of-execution-propertychanges), for which the order is undefined. Instead I am asking about the order of execution *between* states.

Take the following example:

```
Item {
    id: root

    state: ""
    states: [
        State {
            name: alpha
            PropertyChanges {
                target: objectA
                visible: true
            }
        },
        State {
            name: beta
            PropertyChanges {
                target: objectB
                visible: true
            }
        },
        State {
            name: gamma
            extends: alpha
            PropertyChanges {
                target: objectB
                visible: true
            }
        },
    ]

    Item {
        id: objectA
        visible: false
        ...
    }

    Item {
        id: objectB
        visible: false
        ...
    }
}
```

If `state` changes from `alpha` to `beta`, do the `PropertyChanges` of `alpha` get undone before the `PropertyChanges` of `beta` get applied? i.e. does `objectA` become hidden before `objectB` becomes visible?

And what's the situation when changing from `beta` to `gamma`? Does `objectB` temporarily get hidden and if so, does this happen before or after `objectA` becomes visible?

Comment: My guess would be that the leaving of state is processed first and then the entering of state, but I don't have official information. You could try by putting slow running transitions in between

Comment: My guess is that it is not defined meaning it might be one way around at the moment but could change in a future version of Qt. But that's why I've asked the question, in case anyone has a definitive answer. I wouldn't want to risk production code on behaviour that isn't documented.

Comment: Valid point, I find the documents about QML are still not up to a good level and the breaking changes between `controls 1.0` and `controls 2.0` annoying. But I would ask this question on the Qt forum to get a more definitive answer from the guys themselves

Comment: I haven't found authority on this, but I suspect that no property changes get "undone". How would the code know what the property used to be before it entered the state that you are now leaving? I would think that you would need to execute any "undoing" of a property in the property changes of the new state.

Answer (score 0):

Transitions between states are "linear," meaning only the differences are applied. [The State Machine Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine-api.html) has all the documentation I believe (this is what QML States and Transitions use behind the scenes). You may find the section [Using Restore Policy...](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine-api.html#using-restore-policy-to-automatically-restore-properties) especially relevant, and it states (emphasis mine):

> When this restore policy is set, the machine will automatically restore all properties. If it enters a state **where a given property is not set**, it will first search the hierarchy of ancestors to see if the property is defined there. If it is, the property will be restored to the value defined by the closest ancestor. If not, it will be restored to its initial value (i.e. the value of the property before any property assignments in states were executed.)

Restore policy is set in the different `*Changes` QML types (e.g. `PropertyChanges::restoreEntryValues`) and is usually `true` by default.

Behavior can be controlled more specifically by using `Transition`(s) which correspond to the `State`(s).

You could easily test this for your specific use case by implementing event listeners and printing the output (e.g. `onVisibleChanged: console.log(visibile)`).

Comment: OP is not talking about the State Machine Frameworks, he is talking about Qt Quick Item States so your first part is not really relevant.

Comment: @GrecKo So you're saying the State Machine is NOT what QtQuick Items use for States and Transitions?  Or did you not read that far into my answer?

Comment: Yes, I am saying that the state machine framework is not related to the state system of QtQuick Items. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-statemachine-state.html VS http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-state.html